# How to hide and display with js

Tags: javascript, html

How can I use javascript to toggle a class?

I attempted to colorize clicked-on text by giving the element a class, and that works (the text turns red).

But when I click on the same element twice, the class is not removed. I used toggle class for this but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const txts = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');

const txtColor = (txt) => {
  txt.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('txt')) {
      txts.forEach(txt => txt.classList.remove('red'));
      e.target.classList.toggle('red');
    }
  });
}

txtColor(document.querySelector('ul'));
<ul>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This line : txtColor(document.querySelector('ul')); , you just add event listener to "ul", not "li". so it have not class txt. Try change it

Comment: Your `ul` element, has **not** any class

Comment: Hi @DuyNguyễnKhánh - this question is still open. If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below any answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, please choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside an answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer (to close the question). That would help us out. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the textColor() function, so let's remove that. Then, it might be easier to compose your logic if you move the toggle function into its own function.

One place to be careful is when you are toggling the classes. In your original code, you cannot toggle the same LI off / on / off / on.

Here's why:

First, the code removes the red class from all the LIs (a good strategy) - but then, `toggle` is used to toggle the clicked LI's class.

Think about that... If the LI is already red, then you remove the class from *all* LIs (now none of them are red), then you toggle the LI that was already red, it will turn red again - and it looks like nothing happened. But it went red -> nothing -> red *very, very fast*. *Too fast to see it happen.*

Therefore, you can first check if the LI already has the red class, and only toggle it if it didn't already have that class.

This structure might help you to see it better.

```js
const txts = document.querySelectorAll('.txt');

txts.forEach((txt) => {
  txt.addEventListener('click', (e) => toggleColor(e));
});

function toggleColor(e){
  const doRed = e.target.classList.contains('red');
  txts.forEach(txt => txt.classList.remove('red'));
  if (!doRed) e.target.classList.toggle('red');
}
```

```css
.red{
  color: red;
}
li{
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
  <li class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
</ul>
```